# SuperCollider FreqScope: change the frequency resolution

Tags: user-interface, fft, supercollider

For some reason setting a non-default value for the width argument of FreqScope only makes the window bigger, the width of the displayed frequencies remaining unchanged. Could someone help me out?
I'm using SC 3.5.3 on Windows 7. Thanks in advance!

PS. Just updated to 3.6.1, the problem remains unsolved. Might be some issue with buffer size but since FreqScope.new allocates a buffer automatically I don't know how to change that...if that even is the problem.

(PPS this question is asked on behalf of someone else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the constructor args are just about how to size the actual window, they're not about the frequency analysis. The FFT analysis is pretty much hardcoded as 2048 bins.

If you look at the source code of `PlusFreqScope` there's a method called `initFreqScope` where it sets `bufSize = 2048`. You may be able to edit that and recompile, but you probably can't change it on the fly because the number is used in a lot of the class's "preparation" such as creating synths etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on SC 3.10.2, and it looks like this is supprted language-side now with a `bufsize` argument: http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Stethoscope.html

I'm using the `bufsize` arg like this: `s.scope(bufsize: 128)`

(The default bufsize is too large to catch quick percussive events that fall out of phase. It's super visually obvious when beatboxing, so that's how I found this question.)

Comment: Oh wait, exuse me, that's not the FreqScope. The FreqScope still doesn't have that option.

I'll leave this up for informational purposes, but it's not a correct answer.